# Regex improvement match

Tags: javascript, regex

I need some help to improve a regex!
In JavaScript I have a regular expression which looks for pairs of numbers in a filename

```
var nums = str.match(/[\d]{1,}[\d]{1,}/gi);
```

This will match

- DV_Banner_1200x627.jpg
- DV_Banner_1200y627.jpg
- DV_Banner_1200 x 627.jpg
- DV_Banner_1200 x627.jpg
- DV_Banner_1200 627.jpg

with (1200,627)
I have tried to improve the reg ex, just incase there are more than two pairs of numbers, to look for the following
number(1 digit or more) + whitspace(1 or more) + x (zero or once) + whitspace(1 or more) + number(1 digit or more)

Which should fail on the second example (using a 'y' instead on an 'x'), which I thought would be:

```
[\d]{1,}[\s]?[x]?[\s]?[\d]{1,}
```

but it grabs all the digits in

- DV_Banner_1200 x 627 01.jpg

with (1200,627,01) whereas I only want the first two numbers. I've written the code to deal only with the first two, but I was wondering where I was going wrong. Only a level 17 regex wizard can save me now! Thanks

Comment: Not very related but you can improve readability of your regex a little. There is no need to surround `\d` with `[]`. Also `{1,}` can be represented as `+`, so `[\d]{1,}[\d]{1,}` can be rewritten as `\d+\d+`.

Comment: @Pshemo: and `\d+\d+` -- at least 2 digits -- can, in turn, efficiently be written as both `\d\d+` and `\d{2,}`.

Comment: @Jongware Yes, that is also very good point. Using this form is first step to [catastrophic-backtracking](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used `\d+\s?x?\s?\d+` as my regex (same thing just replacing `+` for `{1,}` and removing the unnecessary `[]`). You can see the outcome of it [here](http://regex101.com/r/jL7gH5/1).

The reason it's matching the `01` is because of all the `?`. So it's matching the first `/d+` (1 digit: `0`), and then 0 of `\s`, 0 of `x`, and 0 of `\s` followed by `\d+` (another 1 digit: `1`)

The regex

```
(\d+)(?:\s?x\s?|\s)(\d+)
```

should do the trick. [Test it here](http://regex101.com/r/jL7gH5/2)

`(?:...)` is a non-capture group. So it allows alternation while not assigning a back reference to it. This part matches the characters in between the two numbers (either has an `x` or a `<space>`).

Answer (score 0):

Just try with following regex:

```
(\d+)(?:(?: ?x ?)| )(\d+)
```

[demo](http://regex101.com/r/yE3jC5/3)

Answer (score 0):

You say you want "one or more" whitespace characters between the "x", but you have used the `?` quantifier which means "zero or one". Thus, because you've also marked the "x" as optional, it will match any two-or-more digit number: Your first `[\d]{1,}` will match against `0` then your second one will match on `1`.

Note that you do not need to enclose single atoms into a character range: `[\d]` can be more simply written as `\d`. Also `{1,}` -- meaning "one or more" -- is more easily encoded as `+`.

As you want "one or more" whitespace character on either side of the "x", I would go with:

```
\d+(?:(?:\s+x\s+)|\s+)\d+
```

Note that `(?: ... )` is a "non-capture group", so these bits won't form part of your match array. However, I don't think you want "one or more" whitespace character, as that won't match your first example. Instead, try this:

```
\d+(?:(?:\s*x\s*)|\s+)\d+
```

Where the `*` quantifier means "zero-or-more".